# how to solve the issue of "referer value is wrong" in form sending?

Tags: php, javascript, html, referer

I'm a user of a certain forum, but recently my IP adress has been being blocked.That's not my fault but some users probalbly broke the rule and his ISP or IP address is same or close to mine, so I was enmeshed.
I rent a web server, so now I try to post comments to the forum from my server, but it fails.
When I post a comment using a form in the site, the error says that the referer was wrong.

I tried `header()` function using PHP but it doesn't work.
I tries to change referer but still it doesn't work.
I think if I could have a client in my web server, the IP and host change in posting comments, without changing referer information.But I don't know how to do this.

The restriction is temporary, maybe a few weeks, so I don't necessarily need a perfect and permanent solution.

Is there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Please show us how exactly you are using your server. It's a PHP script? Then post its code. Did you just install a proxy? Then it seems to suppress the `referer` header.

Comment: Hi,Bergi.You know, this is kinda security issue, so I don't expect concrete advise, vice versa. My php code doesn't work, so not worth to post it because my aim is not to improve my wrong code, but want to know is it possible to change referer information by using php, or by other ways. By the way, I don't install a proxy, long time ago, I have tried proxy, but didn't work so I don't like using proxy.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but if you don't show us your code (working or not) we can't help you on integrating a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If they're blocking you based on IP address, then it's the web IP address of your local network that they're blocking. If they've decided to block a range of IPs then you have a larger problem depending on your host.

A few things you can try:

1. Chances are (unless this is a work account) that you're using a dynamic ip address from your host. A lot of work accounts use a dynamic IP too, but you would need access to the modem (since you're probably not the corporate network administrator). Sometimes to get a new IP address from a completely different range by unplugging your cable or DSL modem and plugging it back in after about 30 seconds. Most electronics clear instantaneously (unless they have an onboard battery backup), but in the case of network components they purposely build in a few seconds of wait time in DHCP servers before providing a completely different IP address. Usually when I'm having a problem on my local network or doing an upgrade and unplug my modem after about 10 minutes of work when I plug my modem back in I have a new IP so I have to go through all of the trouble of re-whitelisting myself everywhere (so I know this works).
2. You could try connecting to the boards through your cell phone if you can tether your cell phone to your workstation or desktop. This will provide you with an IP address through the cell phone carrier's network (Note: it might violate the TOS).
3. You could do as @Bergi suggested and use a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). Some web browsers (like Opera) allow you to specify a proxy in the browser without forcing all of your desktop traffic to a different network. You can obtain a proxy server address from several resources, but this is [one of my favorites](http://bit.ly/EvPuA). Be sure to use an HTTPS proxy in order to have the best defense against someone packet filtering and catching your credentials. People can still capture the initial handshake for SSL and decrypt your communications (so make sure this is what you want to do.)
4. You can try to force inject headers into the message board and make your server post for you. *Good* forum software will check the `referrer` and the `user_agent` to see if you are a "real person" (however real the programmer felt you needed to prove). If there is a `CAPTCHA` you will need to be able to see the image, hear the sound, or use a plug-in to break it.  (This will require research). Chances are your web server is using a static IP, so there is nothing to prevent the board from blocking this one as well. (You will not be able to change it.) If the web host has strict guidelines about using their servers for this sort of thing it might *cost you your account*. *I will not provide an example for this on this board.* But you can check out a book called [*WebBots, Spiders, and Screen Scrapers*](http://webbotsspidersscreenscrapers.com/).

Comment: The OP was not asking about working around the blocked IP address - he solved that via posting from his server. He only is asking why the posts from his server get rejected because of wrong `REFERER` header, and how to fix that.

Comment: To AbsoluteƵERØ and Bergi> yes, working around would also be appreciated, thanks. My circumstance doesn't allow to use 1 and 2.I now tried 3 but the board doesn't display my comment so using proxy, even using my country's proxy, is rejected by the board.I still have some idea so I try that later...after that i response again.

Comment: @Bergi the OP was stating their problem was their IP was blocked and even though they were trying to use php they couldn't figure out how to change their referrer in that instance. The original underlying issue was that they could not post to the boards. Referrer would only be the beginning of the issue if they were trying to post to something like *vbulletin.*